# Populating Java multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, coldfusion

I'm new to Java and My example of what I am attempting to accomplish is a ColdFusion structure. Using the following data structure as an example.

```
 id     color
 50     blue
 60     red
 70     green
 80     yellow
```

I want to create a Java multidimensional array from a query resultSet that looks like this.

```
 1 id    50
   color blue
 2 id    60
   color red
 3 id    70
   color green
 4 id    80
   color yellow
```

My goal is to use the returned array to populate a JSP page with data. I am attempting to allow my code to accommodate varying numbers of rows returned by a query.  My current code is as follows.

```
 private static String[][][] query(Connection connection) throws SQLException{

      Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT colors.id,colors.color FROM colors");
      int size;
      resultSet.last();
      size = resultSet.getRow();
      resultSet.beforeFirst();

      ResultSetMetaData rsltmetadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
      int colCount = rsltmetadata.getColumnCount();

      String[][][] rlstSetArray = new String[size][colCount][];

      int m = 0;
      while(resultSet.next()) {
           ++m; 
           for (int j=1; j <= colCount; j++){
                System.out.println(m);
                System.out.println(rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j));
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j)));

           }
       }
 }
```

This code produces this out put.

```
 1
 id
 50
 1
 color
 blue
 2
 id
 60
 2
 color
 red
```

etc...

In place of the three System.out.println lines have tried the following options and receive the same message from NetBeans 8.1. 'incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int'

```
 rlstSetArray[m][rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j)] = resultSet.getString(rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j));

 rlstSetArray[m][rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j)] = "'" + resultSet.getString(rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j)) + "'";

 rlstSetArray[m]["'" + rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j) + "'"] = resultSet.getString(rsltmetadata.getColumnName(j));
```

What is causing this message?

Is this going to allow me to retrieve data from the array in the JSP using the column names that are in the second dimension of the array?

Comment: (Edit) The error is because you are using the array like a structure. Arrays must be referenced by index *number*, ie Like this `[0][1]` not `[0]["columnName"]`. Also, do not forget that java arrays are 0-based, not 1-based. (Side note, nothing to do with your question, but do not forget to close all statements, resultsets, connections, etcetera when finished to prevent memory leaks).

Comment: Thanks, that helps me along with the other comments. Once I have it working I will come back to check the answer that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to create POJO wrapper class for your result set instead of 3-dimensional array?

```
public class Color {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then the query method could be simplified:

```
private static List<Color> query(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
    List<Color> colors = new LinkedList();
    ...
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        Color color = new Color();
        color.setName(resultSet.getString(rsltmetadata.getColumnName("color"));
        color.setId(resultSet.getString(rsltmetadata.getColumnName("id"));
        colors.add(color);
    }
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: I used this option because being new to Java it made more sense to me.  Thanks David.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that I am answering your question, but I audibly said "Ouch" when I saw the triple dimension:

```
private static String[][][] query(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
```

Have you considered using a POJO for the data?

```
class ColorMap {
     private final Integer id;
     private final String  color;

     private static HashMap<String, Integer> nameMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

     public ColorMap(int theId, String theColor) {
         id = theId;
         color = theColor;
         addColorToMap();
     }

     private void addColorToMap() {
         ColorMap.nameMap.put(this.color, this.id);
     }

     public static Integer getColorByName(String theName) {
         return ColorMap.nameMap.get(theName);
     }
}
```

You would then populate the map as you extract data from the query, I would use the column names to find their values else be tightly coupled to the query text.

Comment: Well being new to Java there is a lot I do not know. I am looking for ways to accomplish tasks that are considered best practices using my knowledge of PHP and ColdFusion as starting points. Thanks for your suggestion and I will look further in to how I would use that.

Comment: If you think about it, it is not really that much different than what you would do in CF. Multi-dimensional arrays are not really very intuitive in any language. So normally you would package the data into a more intuitive format, like a CFC (or even a "structure"). A POJO uses the same concept.